# Cassandra: Command Not Found

Tags: cassandra, datastax, cqlsh, nodetool

I am currently working on the Cassandra tutorials about data modeling. I cannot understand why whenever I try to run the cassandra service from the bin folder I receive the error:

> "Cassandra: command not found".

The same happens if I try to run nodetool, or cqlsh utilities. Can anybody help me to resolve the problem?

Answer (score 6):

**All the cassandra binary are in the `$CASSANDRA_HOME/bin` folder.**

If you run command from the `CASSANDRA_HOME` then use :

```
bin/cassandra
bin/cqlsh
bin/nodetool
```

Comment: I had to use: sudo sh cqlsh  in $CASSANDRA_HOME/bin

Comment: Did you try with `sudo $CASSANDRA_HOME/bin/cqlsh` ?

Answer (score 1):

I know is too late now, but for anyone experiencing this problem, while you are already in the bin directory, use *./cqlsh < IP >*. Also if you configured a multi node cluster, use *./nodetool status* and check if you have all the IPs there.

Comment: Why? Which is the role of this script?

Answer (score 0):

On macOS,
You must in the `dse` folder, after that `bin/cqlsh`.

Answer (score 0):

You should go first on your Cassandra installation location or folder.
/
    bin/

Then try to run below command:-

bin/cassandra or bin/cassandra -f

But if you have done package installation then  you should try below command:-
sudo service cassandra start

Please go through below link for more details about all other way to start Cassandra.
https://cassandra.apache.org/doc/latest/getting_started/installing.html#installing-the-binary-tarball